# Retrieving all rows of a table without HQL?

Tags: hibernate

I am using Hibernate 4 and would like to simply list all rows of a table. All solutions I found suggest using something like "from tablename", but I would like to avoid hardcoding tablenames in strings.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can use

```
session.createCriteria(MyEntity.class).list();
```

for example.

Comment: How could I sort this?

Comment: session.createCriteria(MyEntity.class).addOrder(Order.asc("age")).list();

Comment: Is there any way to make this type safe?

Comment: The method createCriteria(Class) from the type SharedSessionContract is deprecated.

Comment: @Maske Do you know what to use now?

Answer (score 8):

HQL doesn't use table names. It uses entity names. And entity names are (by default) class names. So you can use

```
String hql = "select a from " + TheEntity.class.getSimpleName() + " a";
```

But I would favor readability over type safety here, and use

```
String hql = "select a from TheEntity a";
```

You should have automated tests for your queries anyway.

Comment: Yes, queries are tested, but your second solution would still mean that the query wouldn't be taken into account by refactoring.

Comment: Yes, but it would be caught by a failing test.

Comment: I agree that in the end its important to get correct results, but as the project is currently in early stages some kind of refactoring happens every week. So properly supporting this is quite vital at the moment.

Comment: Then use my first technique, or use a Criteria.

Answer (score -2):

//Hibernate Class

```
public class CommonDAO<T> {

 Session session = null;
 Transaction transaction = null;
 private Class<T> clazz;

 public CommonDAO(){ //constructor
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    Type genericSuperclass = this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    if (genericSuperclass instanceof ParameterizedType) {
      ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) genericSuperclass;
      Type type = pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
      clazz = (Class<T>) type;
    }
 }

 public T listById(Object id) {
  T object = null;
  try {
   object = (T) session.get(clazz, (Serializable) id);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return object;
 }
}
```

//User Class

```
public class UserDAO extends CommonDAO<UserMaster> { // Here UserMaster is pojo

 public UserDAO() {
  super();
 }

 public static void main(String ar[]) {
  UserMaster user = new UserDAO().listById(1); // 1 is id
  System.out.println(user.getUserName());
 }
}
```

Comment: Don't do any such stuff with session in constructors

Comment: @dikkini Why is it so ? can you please explain that to me .

Comment: It is so because your session stays open. What you want to do is *open*, *query*, *close* otherwise you will run into problems with scale.