# hibernate: how to select all rows in a table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, postgresql

I try to do something like `Select * from LogEntry` with Hibernate.
insert works fine:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

[...]
protected EntityManager manager;

protected final String tableName = "LogEntry";

public DatabaseImpl(DB_TYPE db) {
    this.db = db;
    if (entityManagerFactory != null && entityManagerFactory.isOpen()) {
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }
    entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(db.getPersUnit());
    manager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}
public void insert(LogEntry entry) {

    manager.getTransaction().begin();
    manager.persist(entry);
    manager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

But when I try to get the inserted values using this method:
    public LogEntryList getAll() {

```
    manager.getTransaction().begin();

    Query query = manager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + ";");
    ArrayList<LogEntry> entries = (ArrayList<LogEntry>) query.getResultList();
    manager.getTransaction().commit();

    return new LogEntryList(entries);
}
```

I always get the Exception: 
`java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to de.motza.entities.LogEntry`

I know the problem is the casting of the Query result to the object, but I can't find anywhere how to cast the objects properly, or how to get more than one row from the table.

does anybody have any advice?
If requested, I can post my persistence.xml and more code

Comment: which version of hibernate you have used?

Comment: try this  Query query = manager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + ";", LogEntry.class);
    List<LogEntry> entries =  query.getResultList();

Comment: hibernate entityManager 4.3.8.Final

Comment: Please review the answers given below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Becuase you have used nativeQuery so you need to transfer result by using `setResultTransormer` method.

```
Query query = manager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + ";");
query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(LogEntry.class))
ArrayList<LogEntry> entries = (ArrayList<LogEntry>) query.getResultList();
```

Comment: where do you get Transformers.aliasToBean() come from?

Answer (score 5):

For starters, you should try to take advantage of HQL, Hibernate Query Language.  In the example you gave above, you are trying to execute a native SQL query.  The reason you are getting the `ClassCastException` is that the native query is circumventing the framework and returning raw `Object`s instead of the type you want.

Try using this code instead for your `SELECT *`:

```
String hql = "from LogEntry";
Session session = entityManagerFactory.openSession();
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List<LogEntry> logEntries = query.list();      // no ClassCastException here
```

Comment: While not exactly what the user wanted, this is certainly beneficial information. It was for me. Thank you for your answer @Tim Biegeleisen :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use
`session.createCriteria(MyEntity.class).list();`
for example.

ref: [Retrieving all rows of a table without HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084143/retrieving-all-rows-of-a-table-without-hql)

Comment: The method createCriteria(Class) from the type SharedSessionContract is deprecated now.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is, that you are sending a native query which will return an Object[] array, with one value for each dolumn. You do not need to call a native query, but a hibernate query, for example...

`manager.createQuery("SELECT l FROM LogEntry");`

see, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330752/basic-hibernate-select-all-syntax).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring HibernateDaoSupport, you can use these methods to load Entities from database:

a) single entity by ID

```
@Override
public DeleteProcessNotification getDeleteProcessNotificationById(Long id) {
    return this.getHibernateTemplate().load(DeleteProcessNotification.class, id);
}
```

b) all entities

```
@Override
public List<DeleteProcessNotification> getDeleteProcessNotificationsInQueue() {
    return this.getHibernateTemplate().loadAll(DeleteProcessNotification.class);
}
```

c) entities with a HQL query

```
@Override
public List<DeleteProcessNotification> getPrioritizedDeleteProcessNotifications() {
    return (List<DeleteProcessNotification>) this.getHibernateTemplate().find(
            "FROM DeleteProcessNotification dpn \n" +
                    "WHERE dpn.priority = 'HIGH'");
}
```

HibernateDaoSupport documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/support/HibernateDaoSupport.html

Answer (score 0):

As i know getResultList() gives you a List...not a generic List. So if you want to get a generic list you have to use

```
TypedQuery<Person>
```

insted of

```
Query
```

This is the link i got the information.

[Cast to something the result of Query.getResultList()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957394/java-persistence-cast-to-something-the-result-of-query-getresultlist)

I don't know much about Hibernate. i hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> list = null;

TypedQuery<String> query = sessionfactory.openSession().createQuery("from yourTableName");

list = query.getResultList();
```

`yourTableName` can be your `@Entity` class